# Creating a static and dynamic lib at once

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

How can I create a static and a dynamic library at once? I am using qt 5.1. I would like to have a `.pro` file which does both lib types. I would need it for windows and linux. I found something like this:

```
CONFIG += staticlib
```

But how can I also build the shared one?

Here is my example at the moment (for the .so):

```
ROOT_DIR = ./..
INCLUDE_DIR = $$ROOT_DIR/include
SRC_DIR = $$ROOT_DIR/src
BIN_DIR = $$ROOT_DIR/bin
LIB_DIR = $$ROOT_DIR/lib
MAKE_DIR = .

unix {
MOC_DIR = $$ROOT_DIR/moc
OBJECTS_DIR = $$ROOT_DIR/obj
}

win32 {
MOC_DIR = $$ROOT_DIR/moc.win
OBJECTS_DIR = $$ROOT_DIR/obj.win
}

QT       -= gui

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = lib

DESTDIR = $$BIN_DIR

DEFINES += TEST_LIBRARY

SOURCES += Test.cpp

HEADERS += Test.h\
        test_global.h
```

Can somebody tell my how to add the static library, also? And as I said, it should also work for windows, so, I need the right libs there. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 6):

No answer yet? I've been also scratching my head until I came with this solution:

`CONFIG += shared_and_static build_all`

This produces two versions of compiled objects (mine are identical) in two sparate directories (two 'modes') called `shared` and `static` and two makefiles (`Makefile.Shared` and `Makefile.Static`) to be able to make both targets.

By adding `build_all`, both targets are made in a row.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states, this has nothing to do with the `CONFIG` variable. You can leave it empty, or use one of the valid values. Check the [qmake variable reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html).

The variable `TEMPLATE` is the one you are looking for, and it should have the value `lib`. This will be enough to build both static and dynamic libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I am using 
`CONFIG += staticlib` and
`CONFIG += lib`
he just builds the static one. If I only use `CONFIG += lib` he makes just the dynamic lib. Any idea?

Comment: Well, that is odd... This line here (Qt 5.2 on Windows, Qt 4.8 on Linux) works fine, generating both static and dynamic libs. I'll edit my answer to something that makes more sense (despite I've never needed it).

Comment: Nope! I tried `CONFIG += staticlib lib` and `CONFIG += lib staticlib` and both just generate the .a :(

Comment: @immerhart Sorry, this is completely wrong. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-common-projects.html#library
I guess it is not possible. If you use `TEMPLATE = lib` and `CONFIG = staticlib` he just builds the static one if you get rid of the `CONFIG` he just make the dynamic one... :(

Comment: I really think this have something to do with your environment. I have 4 different installations of 4 different versions of Qt, 2 running on Windows and 2 on Linux, all of them give me the same behavior: `TEMPLATE = lib`, `CONFIG` isn't even being set in my .pro file, and both shared and static libs are being successfully built.